# Android: Populating a GridtView from the SQLite Database

Tags: sqlite, gridview

Gridview is not populating any data from Sqlite database while saving the data in to database. Logcat is not generating any error also.

My DB is.

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  //String where = null;
  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + DATAALL_TABLE, null);
  if (c != null) {
    c.moveToFirst();
  }
  return c;
}
```

Mainactivity.

```
public void populateListView() {

  Cursor cursor = db.getAllRows();
  String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {
    DBHelper.COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID1, DBHelper.FIELD_MATERIALDESC, DBHelper.FIELD_MATERIALNUM
  };
  int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {
    R.id.textView1, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView2
  };
  SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
  myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIDs, 0);
  GridView myList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
  myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

}
```

Post to the honorable member @MikeT advise its works fine but need alignment ,

as is

[image]

expected format

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue, assuming that there is data in the table, is likely that R.id.textView1 .... 3 are nothing to do with the layout passed to the SimpleCursorAdapter. i.e. Your issue is likely to do with the combination of the layout passed to the SimpleCursorAdapter and the Id's of the views passed as the **to** id's.

If you were to use :-

```
    gridview = this.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    csr = DBHelper.getAllRows();
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getBaseContext(),
            //android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            android.R.layout.activity_list_item,
            csr,
            new String[]{
                    SO50674769DBHelper.COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID1
                    //SO50674769DBHelper.FIELD_MATERIALDESC,
                    //SO50674769DBHelper.FIELD_MATERIALNUM
            },
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, //<<<< ID of the available view
            0
    );
    gridview.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

Then result would be along the lines of :-

[image]

Changing to use a different stock layout and 2 fields as per :-

```
    gridview = this.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    csr = DBHelper.getAllRows();
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getBaseContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            //android.R.layout.activity_list_item, //<<<< Changed Layout
            csr,
            new String[]{
                    SO50674769DBHelper.COURSES_KEY_FIELD_ID1,
                    SO50674769DBHelper.FIELD_MATERIALDESC,
                    //SO50674769DBHelper.FIELD_MATERIALNUM
            },
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, //<<<< ID's of the 2 views
            0
    );
    gridview.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

- Note The DatabaseHelper class is so named for my convenience.

Would result in :-

[image]

As such I suspect that you need to change the layout to a one of your own.

Additionally, as hinted at your `getAllRows` method is not at all ideal.

- Checking for a null Cursor is useless as a Cursor returned from rawQuery will not be null. It may be empty in which case the Cursor `getCount` method would return 0 ().
- moveToFirst is also a waste.

Simply have :-

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  return db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + DATAALL_TABLE, null);
}
```

Comment: thanks its works. but gridview alignment need to change , also its allowing me to display more than 2 text. i need to add more than 2. amended requirement given above

Comment: can you advise on below requet

Comment: @Leace me and graphics/ui look don't appear to be that friendly i.e. I'm hopeless which such things. Never even used a gridview, much better to ask a new question on that one.